# Postgresql - Three tables. Two connections. Unrelated result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables **t_items**, **market**, **items_likes**.

```
create table t_items (
item_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
title varchar);

create table market(
market_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
item_id varchar references t_items(item_id),
title varchar);

CREATE TABLE items_likes (
like_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
item_id varchar references t_items(item_id),
user_id varchar);
```

In the end, I want to get a result that includes the number of **likes** and the number of **markets**.

```
select
  t_items.item_id,
  t_items.title,
  count(items_likes.item_id) as likes_count,  
  count(market.item_id) as market_count
from market
inner join t_items on market.item_id = t_items.item_id
inner join items_likes on t_items.item_id = items_likes.item_id
group by t_items.item_id;
```

But when I add the number of **likes** to the request, I lose the result of the number of **markets**.

Here is a working example:
https://rextester.com/live/HVUGW7783

How to make a request with the result of the exact number of likes and stores?

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate by item and count the number of distinct markets and likes to remove the issue with doubles that you would get otherwise when joining across the three tables, like so:

```
select
  t_items.item_id,
  t_items.title,
  count(distinct items_likes.like_id) as likes_count,  
  count(distinct market.market_id ) as market_count
from market
left join t_items on market.item_id = t_items.item_id
left join items_likes on t_items.item_id = items_likes.item_id
group by t_items.item_id
order by t_items.title;
```

The left join is important so that you will still get a row for an item that has, e.g. 3 markets but 0 likes. With an inner join you will only get items with at least one market and at least one like.

Comment: Thanks, it's important for me to have a request with **from market**.

Answer (score 1):

Join 2 queries, the 1st gets the number of likes and the 2nd the number of markets:

```
select t_items.item_id, t_items.title, t.likecounter, t.marketcounter from (
  select t.item_id, t.likecounter, tt.marketcounter from (
    select t_items.item_id, count(items_likes.like_id) likecounter
    from t_items inner join items_likes
    on items_likes.item_id = t_items.item_id
    group by t_items.item_id
  ) t inner join (
    select t_items.item_id, count(market.item_id) marketcounter 
    from t_items inner join market 
    on market.item_id = t_items.item_id 
    group by t_items.item_id
  ) tt
  on tt.item_id = t.item_id
) t inner join t_items
on t_items.item_id = t.item_id
order by t_items.item_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=56f11f42f9a819f06b7ed2156b5642ca)

Comment: Thanks @forpas, maybe there is a simpler version?

Comment: You have 2 unrelated to each other tables: items_likes  and market, so aggregates must be separate for each one and then joined. Also you want in the final results the `title` so again another join. I couldn't think of anything simpler.

Comment: Thanks again.
But my true request is a little longer, but I have no experience. I will definitely learn how to use your agrigat functions.

Comment: Are you using Postgress 11?

Comment: I have the PostgreSQL 9.6.11

Comment: Then what did you ask for in your question? the answer you accepted is exactly the same as your own code with only the distinct part as a difference. I thought you were using Postgress 8.0 and you could not aggregate both columns.

Comment: My request returned an answer in which the number of **likes** overlapped the number of **markets**.